# Efficient way to check and count if a given subtring exists in a string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, count, substring

I have several fasta files (around 40), in which I have a huge amount of sequences (more than 100,000 in each). What I want to do is to check if a given string exists in the different sequences and if it does count in how many. For example,

>Sequence_1
CAUAAAAUUAUAAUGCAUCGUUAUCAGCUGGGUCAUAUGUUAUGACAACGACUUGGCGGA
AUACUAGUAAGUUGUCCUUUCCACUUAAUUGAAACGAUUUGCGCAGGAAUUUUGUGAUAA
UUAUC**AAAAAAA**

>Sequence_2
CGCAGAUAGAUUCUGGCAGCCCUUGCCUGAUGUAAGCGUGUACGAUUGGAGAAGCCACCU
CCCCAGAUCCGUGCUUCCCCGGACUUGUAGCCCAAAUCGAGUUAAUUACACACUAUUGUG
UAUCCUAUGU

If I wanted to count the number of sequences that have **AAAAAAA** I should get 1, since it only exists in one of the two sequences.

In order to search for the strings I've tried the Boyer-moore-horspool and Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithms. The problem is that I have a list of 20,000 strings that need to be checked so it means that for every string it has to check over 400,000 sequences. In my code I use for loops and the way I have the data make me use 3 loops indented which I know is too much:

```
for w in words: 
    for x in list_files:
        with open(directory ,"r") as f:
           for seq_record in SeqIO.parse((directory), "fasta"):
```

How could I organize my data so it is more efficient or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Why do you not use the [`Seq`](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Seq.html#module-Bio.Seq) function [`find()`](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Seq.html#Bio.Seq.Seq.find) or even `in` rather than code your own string search functions? I would expect that these methods would be well implemented in biopython.

Comment: Further to the above. it might be possible to get improved search performance using regular expressions to search for multiple target strings as a regex pattern. Also I would look at distributing the work over multiple processors using the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) module. You would use a pool of workers that work on a subset of the files and then collate the results as they come back from each subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

At a relatively high level, I would:

1. use a combination of `functools.partial` and `concurrent.futures` to utilize all the available CPU cores by using `ThreadpoolExecutor`
2. use cython / Boost.python / pybind11 to write the implementation of BMH and import it in python (this will prevent internal loop constructs from being written in python)